# Android Studio 2.2.2 LLDB 2.2 update issue

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, lldb

Today I updated my android studio to version V-2.2.2. When I am trying to debug my android application with native code(app-native) I am always getting error message

> C++ debugger package is missing or incompatible, do you want to fix it.

[image]

After updating to lldb 2.2 also I am getting same issue when I try to debug my native c++ code.

[image]

I am using gradle plug in 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.2' for building native ndk code. I have even updated ndk-bundle to latest version 13.0.3315539

Is anybody facing similar issue or able to resolve similar issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved issue by performing following steps

1. Go to android-sdk folder on your file System, Locate folder lldb and delete folder lldb. (

> For safety purpose you can keep backup or rename folder.

)
 2. Now from android studio Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tools and update lldb option. Click on Apply. It will download LLDB 2.2 
 3. Now try to debug C++ code and debugging is working fine as expected.

Issue was arising due to some conflict between older downloaded version LLDB 2.1 and newer LLDB  version 2.2

Comment: Thanks, that got me past the issue of constantly being asked to install lldb. It still won't break in native code though. I set project to both Hyrbrid and Native and neither breaks. Any other tips?

Comment: There is no issue or any other break found in work environment with above changes still for safety you can rename current lldb folder as lldb_2.1(or something full) so that you can revert changes easily.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with Android Studio 2.3 Beta 3. I tried all the solutions I could found but no one works. I used the Quick Fix Option by press Yes below. However, it then report failed to download LLDB 2.3.

I fixed this by selecting "Beta" channel in my Updates settings and then run Quick Fix Again. The channel was changed to Stable somehow. So it always failed to download LLDB 2.3

Hope this helps to people might having the same issue and found here.

[image: Quick Fix Option]
[image: Failed To Download LLDB 2.3]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit configurations... > Debugger > Choose Java as debug Type > Apply

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SDK Manager and remove LLDB. (from Launch standalone SDK Manager)
2. Close SDK Manager.
3. Re-open SDK Manager and go to SDK Tools.
4. Re-install LLDB