# Android Studio: LLDB won't install correctly

Tags: lldb, android-studio-2.3, android-sdk-manager

Android Studio: version 2.3.2
Tools are up to date with latest versions.
In SDK Manager, I check LLDB and click Apply.
It says it installed LLDB correctly, but the SDK Manager still shows it is not installed.
When I run the debugger it has to re-install LLDB every time.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40170045/4915707

Go to android-sdk folder on your file System, Locate folder lldb and
delete folder lldb. (For safety purpose you can keep backup or rename
folder.)

Now from Android studio Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK
Tools and update lldb option. Click on Apply. It will download LLDB
2.2.3 and install it properly.

Issue was arising due to some conflict between older downloaded
version LLDB and newer LLDB version